# Variable/Lexical environments

Tags: javascript

As said in [**sec 10.4.3**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3)

> The following steps are performed when control enters the execution
>   context for function code contained in function object F, a caller
>   provided thisArg, and a caller provided argumentsList:
>
> 1. If the function code is strict code, set the ThisBinding to thisArg.
> 2. Else if thisArg is null or undefined, set the ThisBinding to the global object.
> 3. Else if Type(thisArg) is not Object, set the ThisBinding to ToObject(thisArg).
> 4. Else set the ThisBinding to thisArg.
> 5. Let localEnv be the result of calling NewDeclarativeEnvironment passing the value of the [[Scope]] internal property of F as the
>      argument.
> 6. Set the LexicalEnvironment to localEnv.
> 7. Set the VariableEnvironment to localEnv.
> 8. Let code be the value of F‘s [[Code]] internal property.
> 9. Perform Declaration Binding Instantiation using the function code code and argumentsList as described in 10.5.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
function foo(){
    var a={p:'p'};
    o={c:'c'};
}
```

Thus we have the following:

1. Code of our function isnt a strict code
2. `thisArg` is null hence, `ThisBinding` set to the global object
3. ---
4. ---
5. I dont understand what bindings will be contains `environment record` represented by `[[Scope]]` internal property.
6. Set the `LexicalEnvironment` to environment which geted at step 5.
7. Set the `VariableEnvironment` to environment which geted at step 5.
8. Perform declaration binding instatiation.

At step 8 bindings are created in the VariableEnvironment, but not in LexicalEnvironment. But in [**sec 10.3**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3) said that

> When an execution context is created its LexicalEnvironment and
>   VariableEnvironment components initially have the same value.

**Question:**

Why just after creation of execution context LexicalEnvironment and VariableEnvironment is still equal in my case above?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. `LexicalEnvironment` and `VariableEnvironment` get the same value assigned in 6 and 7.

Comment: @Felix Kling At step 8 of context creation variables and functions declared in the code will be added as bindings in VariableEnvironment‘s Environment Record. But what about LexicalEnvironment? Will this bindings added to LexicalEnvironment at step 8? And what is the `[[Scope]]` internal property of function in my specific case?

Comment: That's a good question. I would assume that is similar with objects: LexicalEnvironment and VariableEnvironment refer to the same environment, and hence any changes made to that environment are visible through both components. In your example, `[[Scope]]` would refer to the lexical environment of the global execution context, since you defined the function in global scope. See http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13

Comment: @Felix Kling VariableEnvironment component never changes, hence is referential relationship between Lexical and Variable environments broken just after executional context creation?

Comment: VariableEnvironment doesn't get a new value assigned, but the value is *mutated*. LexicalEnvironment on the other can get a new value assigned, e.g. when entering a `with` statement.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand your question, but this is how I understand sec 10.4.3 :

***steps 1 to 4*** are dealing with the value of this. Basically, in strict mode, `this` will be left to a `null` or `undefined` value instead of defaulting to the global object (`window` in case of a browser). This covers the cases when a function is not invoked through usual object or event handler mechanisms.

***step 5 to 7*** mean that a new naming environment is created each time you enter a function.
It describes the creation of this environment, which is linked to the previous one to form the current name scope.

For each new function, two environments are co-existing.
When a name is resolved, Lexical environment is searched first, then Variable environment. If both searches fail, the process is repeated at the upper level of the environment chain, until the 'catch-all' global scope is encountered. In this scope, all identifiers are handled as properties of the global (`window`) object. You can picture it as the whole code being enclosed in a `with (window)` block.

Lexical environment can be seen as a temporary augmentation of the variable scope.
Lexical and Variable environments are ***functionnally*** identical until you alter the lexical environment with two specific statements: `with` or `catch`. It does not mean they are implemented as identical data structures.

In terms of implementation, you could imagine the lexical environment as an empty list and the variable environment as a list containing all local variable and parameter names.
When a `catch` or `with` statement is encountered, the lexical list is populated with new names that will take precedence over the ones stored in the variable list.

**`catch`** will simply make its argument available for name resolution (i.e. allow you to reference the exception parameter). No big deal since the new name is just as explicit as a function parameter.

**`with`** is a rather more dangerous beast. It will create a new environment with the names of all properties of the object passed as its argument. The scope will consist of the chain of *variable* environments plus this new *lexical* environment.
Here the new names available for resolution are 'hidden' inside the object.
For instance:

```
var a = 'a', b = 'surprise!', o = {a:'a'};
with (o) { a = b; }
console.log (a+" "+b+" "+o.a);
```

will yield

```
a surprise! surprise!
```

`a` is resolved as `o.a` since `o` contains a property named `a`.
`b` is not found inside the *lexical* environment and thus the current *variable* environment is tried and variable `'b'` is found.
This is a pretty dangerous mechanism, because if you believe an object contains a given property while it actually doesn't, you will instead reference a variable outside the current scope.
For instance, a simple typo like this:

```
with (element.style) {leftt = '10px';}
```

will set the `window.leftt` property to `'10px'`, unless you happen to have declared a variable named `leftt` somewhere in the current scope.

Now if you give silly names like 'i' or 'j' to your object properties, chances are you will clobber a random loop index somewhere up the scope chain while believing you are setting the property of an object.

***step 8*** describes the parameters binding once the function scope is established. Basically, the parameters are bound with the values and their names are added to the variable environment.

The whole point of keeping two separate environments is that the hoisting mechanism always uses the ***variable*** environment chain as a scope.

The idea is that a variable or function should behave as if it had been declared at the top of the current scope block, so for instance a function declared inside a with block should not resolve its names with the object properties exposed by the with statement.

Frankly this is a rather moot point, since ECMA spec does not allow function declarations inside blocks, although most implementations do, with varrying results.

Now for your example:

```
function foo(){
    var a={p:'p'};
    o={c:'c'};
}
```

Your function does not contain any `with` or `catch` statements, so the scope chain inside 'foo()' is just a list of two variable environments :

```
global (a bunch of DOM objects all seen as properties of 'window')
    function foo (var a)
```

once you call foo(),

- `a` will resolve as foo's local variable, will be created as an object with the property `p` of value `'p'` (and garbage collected as soon as you leave foo(), unless you manage to reference it from a persistent variable).
- `o` will not be found in foo's variable environment, so it will be caught by the 'catch-all' global scope and thus resolved as a (new) property of the `window` object. It will create a `window.o.c` property with the value `'c'`.

Does that answer somewhat to your question?

Comment: Super useful answer in general for understand the difference between lexical and variable environments :)