# VariableEnvironment's functions

Tags: javascript

## Variable/Lexical Environment component of execution context

**Question 1**:

For what `VariableEnvironment` component of exection context is needed?
As said in spec LexicalEnvironment component

> used to resolve identifier references made by code
>   within this execution context.

But `VariableEnvironment` component used to

> holds bindings created by VariableStatements and FunctionDeclarations
>   within this execution context.

Ok, but evaluation of `PrimaryExpression:Identifier` is execution with `LexicalEnvironment` component, not `VariableEnvironment` of running execution context:

> 1. Let env be the running execution context‘s LexicalEnvironment.
> 2. If the syntactic production that is being evaluated is contained in a strict mode code, then let strict be true, else let strict be false.
> 3. Return the result of calling GetIdentifierReference function passing env, Identifier, and strict as arguments.

Thus is VariableEnvironment need for bindings storage only?

Establishing function context is occuring as:
[**sec. 10.4.3**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3)

> 1. If the function code is strict code, set the ThisBinding to thisArg.
> 2. Else if thisArg is null or undefined, set the ThisBinding to the global object.
> 3. Else if Type(thisArg) is not Object, set the ThisBinding to ToObject(thisArg).
> 4. Else set the ThisBinding to thisArg.
> 5. Let localEnv be the result of calling NewDeclarativeEnvironment passing the value of the [[Scope]] internal property of F as the
>      argument.
> 6. Set the LexicalEnvironment to localEnv.
> 7. Set the VariableEnvironment to localEnv.
> 8. Let code be the value of F‘s [[Code]] internal property.
> 9. Perform Declaration Binding Instantiation using the function code code and argumentsList as described in 10.5.

Where at step 9 bindings add to a `VariableEnvironment` only. At step 5 `[[Scope]]` internal property indicates to outer `LexicalEnvironment`. Thus i have question

**Question 2**:
Is it true that just after creation of execution context of function code `LexicalEnvironement`'s initial environment record contains the same bindings that environment record of outer `LexicalEnvironment`?

Consider the following code snippet into the global code?

## Example of function code

```
function bar(){
    var b={b:'b'}
    var o={o:'o'}
}
bar();
```

**Question 3:**

Is it true that just after creation of `bar` execution context before the start of execution function code `VariableEnvironment`'s environment record will be contain `bar-->function bar(){ ... }, b-->{b:'b'}, o--> {o:'o'}`, but `LexicalEnvironment`'s environment record

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**

VariableEnvironment is the leaf of the scope chain at the start of a function. Since
all variables and functions are hoisted at the top of the current function (or global scope), it defines the scope of identifiers visible strictly inside a given function.

LexicalEnvironment extends VariableEnvironment when you use the constructs `with` and `catch`. See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715169/variable-lexical-environments/20822155#20822155) for more details.

Both environments are used for name resolution. LexicalEnvironment is used most of the time, except in function bodies (i.e. a function within a function), where VariableEnvironment (of the parent function) is supposed to be used instead.

As I said in my previous answer, the case is rather unfrequent and various implementations behave differently.

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 'binding storage'.
Bindings take place when applicable (i.e parameters passing or assignment) once the names are resolved, whichever environment allowed the resolution.

Basically, the names inside a VariableEnvironment are those of local variables (bound to heap objects when the variables are assigned) and parameters (bound to the passed values when the function is called, as described in steps 8-9 of spec 10.4.3).

The names in LexicalEnvironment will be either the name of the exception context for a `catch` statement or the names of an object's properties for a `with` statement. They will be bound to their corresponding instances when the statement is evaluated, and disposed of at the end of the statement body.

For instance:

```
function stick_to_top (element)
{
    with (element.style) { top = 0; }
}
stick_to_top (document.getElementById ("wanderer"));
```

binding of `top` will occur when the statement `top = 0;` is executed, during function invokation.

Name resolution will resolve `top` as `element.top` using the Lexical context of `stick_to_top()` enhanced by the `with` statement that will contain the names of all `element.style` properties, and resolve `element` as `stick_to_top()`'s argument using the Variable context of `stick_to_top()`, which contains only the name of the parameter `element`.

In the end, value 0 will be assigned to property style.top of the DOM object having the ID "wanderer" (assuming getElementById() found it, of course).

Now if you're up for a joke, try this :

```
var tip = { style:{top:1}};
var top = { style:'', invaluable_information:42};
var tap = { };
stick_to_top (tip);
stick_to_top (top);
console.log ("tip %o top %o", tip, top);
stick_to_top (tap);
```

result:

```
tip [object Object] top 0
SCRIPT5007: Object expected
```

**tip** behaves just like a regular DOM object since we defined a `style.top` property for it

**tap** does not have a `style` property, so `tap.style` is `undefined` and the interpreter throws an error when trying to process the `with` statement.

**top** is the unlucky one. It does have a `style` property so the with statement is happly creating an empty Lexical environment. Now identifier `top` is nowhere to be found inside `stick_to_top()`, so name resolution goes back to global context where it happily finds an unsuspecting `top` variable. Inevitable tragedy ensues...

***Question 2***

Both Lexical and Variable environments are local to a context. The *scope* is made of a chain of environments, i.e. when resolving a name, if the identifier could not be found in the current environment, parent environments are tried in succession until you reach the toplevel environment where identifiers are considered properties of the global object.

(since you seem to be interrested mostly in variables, I leave aside the function prototype scope for the sake of concision)

So the answer to your question is no. In your example, the lexical environment of the toplevel is the collection of all global variables (i.e. the properties of the `window` object), while the lexical environment of `foo()` is identical to its variable environment, containing only the names of the two locals `b` and `o`.

***Question 3***

It will just contain `b-->{b:'b'}, o--> {o:'o'}`

`bar-->function bar(){ ... }` will be in the toplevel's lexical context.

the `bar` identifier will be a synonym of `window.bar`.

(here again, think of a JavaScript program being enclosed in an implicit `with (window)` statement).