# Value of variable and lexical environment after creating execution context

Tags: javascript

I have global code snippet:

```
function foo(){
    var a={a:'a'};
    var b={b:'b'};
}
```

What is the value of `Variable/LexicalEnvironment` just after creation of `foo`'s execution context? I think that `VariableEnvironment`'s `environment record` must  contain bindings `foo--> function(){ }, a-->{a: 'a'}, b-->{b: 'b'}`, but `LexicalEnvironment`'s `environment record` must contain a `global environment`'s `environment record`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already established in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20715169/218196), `VariableEnvironment` and `LexicalEnvironment` refer to the *same* environment. But the environment which `LexicalEnvironment` refers to might change *during* the execution of the function. From the [spec](http://es5.github.io/#x10.3):

> When an execution context is created its LexicalEnvironment and VariableEnvironment components initially have the same value. The value of the VariableEnvironment component never changes while the value of the LexicalEnvironment component may change during execution of code within an execution context.

So here is what happens when `foo` is about to be executed, in JavaScript-ish pseudo code:

```
// foo.[[scope]] refers to the global lexical environment
localEnv = new NewDeclarativeEnvironment(foo.[[scope]])
LexicalEnvironment = localEnv
VariableEnvironment = localEnv

env = VariableEnvironment.envRec
env.CreateMutableBinding('a', false)
env.SetMutableBinding('a', undefined, false)
env.CreateMutableBinding('b', false)
env.SetMutableBinding('b', undefined, false)
```

I.e. the environment record of the lexical environment has two entries, `a` and `b`. I don't know why it is necessary to have both, `LexicalEnvironment` and `VariableEnvironment`, but that's how the language is designed.

Comment: Rationale: stuff like with. See http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/es5-chapter-3-2-lexical-environments-ecmascript-implementation/

Comment: Mmmh. One could also make the original `VariableEnvironment` just a "property" of the `LexicalEnvironment` I guess. But maybe it's easier to describe when they are separate.

Comment: Your explanation is understandable, thanks! Thus execution context is mentioned just as a simple JS object with `ThisBindings`, `LexicalEnvironment` and `VariableEnvironment` as properties. But it doesn't describe in chapter 10 explicitly. Might it described before 10 chapter?

Comment: @St.Antario: The specification says: *"An execution context is purely a specification mechanism and need not correspond to any particular artefact of an ECMAScript implementation. It is impossible for an ECMAScript program to access an execution context."* It is not an "object", but to make it easier to understand how it works, you can *think of* it as an object.

Answer (score 3):

An execution context contains a lexical environment, a variable environment and a this binding.

[image] ([source](http://es5.github.io/#x10))

So, to clarify:

- An execution context contains both a lexical environment and a variable environment
- They're different things.
- Environment contains two types of environment records

  - declarative environment record - these directly associate an identifier with a language value.
  - object environment record - these define the effect ecmascript elements (such as `with` on the properties of some object.

So - to answer your question.

If we check the spec it clearly states:

> When an execution context is created its **LexicalEnvironment** and **VariableEnvironment** components initially have the same value. The value of the VariableEnvironment component never changes while the value of the LexicalEnvironment component may change during execution of code within an execution context.

So, in your case of entering the function `foo`, the process is specified in [10.4.3](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.3) "entering function code" the VariableEnvironment is:

> Let localEnv be the result of calling NewDeclarativeEnvironment passing the value of the [[Scope]] internal property of F as the argument.
>
> Set the LexicalEnvironment to localEnv.
>
> Set the VariableEnvironment to localEnv.

What is `[[Scope]]`? It's defined when the function is *created* and is specified in [13.2 Creating function objects](http://es5.github.io/#x13.2).

So, like we said before, the `VariableEnvironment` and `LexicalEnvironment` **are identical**, they both have an *empty* (no binding) declarative environment record, and an outer lexical environment reference of the environment to the `[[scope]]`

So, the `[[Scope]]` internal property of `foo` is passed, that is detected by the parsing and contains the references to `a` and `b` and the function `foo` itself.